# Reset Password by retrieving Email from Forget Password View django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, reset-password

in the following code when "forget password" runs it takes "email" input from the user and generates token, using that email and token the user can change their password
but what i want is:
the user only needs to enter "new_password" and "reconfirm_password" and not the email to change the password, the email should be get from "forget password view"
the following code gives this error while executing:
cannot access local variable 'email' where it is not associated with a value

views.py

```
class ChangePasswordView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, token, email):
        context = {}
        try:
            profile_obj = UserAccount.objects.filter(
                forget_password_token=token).first()
            if profile_obj:
                context['email'] = email
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'message': 'Invalid token.'})
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'An error occurred.'})

        return JsonResponse(context)

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        try:
            context = {}
            profile_obj = UserAccount.objects.filter(
                email=email).first()
            if profile_obj:
                context['email'] = email
            new_password = request.data.get('new_password')
            confirm_password = request.data.get('reconfirm_password')
            email = request.data.get('email') 

            print(new_password)

            if email is None:
                return JsonResponse({'message': 'No user email found.'})

            if new_password != confirm_password:
                return JsonResponse({'message': 'Both passwords should be equal.'})

            user_obj = UserAccount.objects.get(email=email)
            user_obj.set_password(new_password)
            user_obj.save()
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Password changed successfully.'})

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'An error occurred.'})


@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class ForgetPasswordView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            email = data.get('email')
            if not UserAccount.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                return JsonResponse({'message': 'No user found with this email.'})

            user_obj = UserAccount.objects.get(email=email)
            token = str(uuid.uuid4())
            user_obj.forget_password_token = token
            user_obj.save()
            send_forget_password_mail(user_obj.email, token)
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'An email has been sent.'})

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'An error occurred.'})

        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Something went wrong.'})
```

Comment: my first read of this code makes me think this is not secure at all: if you're able to get a valid token, you take the email from the view to change the password? Doesn't that mean that any valid user can get a reset token, and then call the view with a different email and they'd be able to change the password of the user with that email?
Don't try to reinvent security. Django has plugins for this https://django-otp-official.readthedocs.io/en/stable/auth.html

Comment: I agree, this is a highly insecure approach. There are lots of third party libraries that handle this stuff for you: https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser

Answer (score 0):

I personally use `rest_framework_simplejwt` to generate a token and send an email with a URL and token to the email from forgot password request. Then on that new URL I submit the new password and decode the token to get the user and change the password.

**User Model**

Here you have access to the refresh and access token but what we want is the access token.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin)
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
import uuid

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    public_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    lastname= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'firstname', 'lastname']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username+'( '+self.email+' )'

    def tokens(self):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token)
        }

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'
        ordering = ('-id',)
```

**Forgot Password View**

You can replace **localhost:8000/set-password/** with reverse URL to your set password endpoint. Once a user is found, a token is generated and sent to users email.

```
class RequestPasswordResetEmail(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = ResetPasswordEmailRequestSerializer

    def post(self, request,  *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=request.data['email'])
            token = RefreshToken.for_user(user).access_token
            absurl = "localhost:8000/set-password/?token="+str(token)
            htmly = get_template('emailTemplates/forgotPassword.html')
            context = {'firstname': user.firstname,
                       "absurl": absurl}
            html_content = htmly.render(context)
            msg = EmailMessage(subject='Password Reset', body=html_content,
                               to=[user.email],
                               from_email=os.environ['EMAIL_SEND_AS'])
            msg.content_subtype = "html"
            msg.send()
            data = {'status': status.HTTP_200_OK, 'msg': 'Email Sent.'}
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            data = {'status': status.HTTP_200_OK, 'msg': 'Email Sent.'}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

**Set Password View**

The token is decoded to get the user id and user password changed otherwise a correct response is given.

```
class SetAccountPasswordAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = EmailVerificationSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        token = request.GET.get('token')
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(
                token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms='HS256')
            user = User.objects.get(id=payload['user_id'])
            user.set_password(request.data['password'])
            user.save()
            return Response({'message': 'Password Set Successfully'},
                                status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            return Response({'message': 'Token Has Expired'},
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except jwt.exceptions.DecodeError:
            return Response({'message': 'Invalid Token'},
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```